# Strip HTML tags from string

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip-tags

I have a website which parses RSS feed from websites and posts them on a page.
The script that runs behind my website, which reads and reformats the RSS feed, is currently stripping all the HTML tags.

Here's the code;
 `$description = strip_tags($description);`

I want to allow tags like `<p>`, `<a>` or `<br />` but if i do that, for some reason my website becomes a mess. Like the header will have a big space above it.
What would be the solution to that?

=== EDIT === (some more code)

`// get all of the sources of news from the database
$get_sources = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."sources ORDER BY last_crawled ASC");
while ($source = $db->fetch_array($get_sources)) {`

```
$feed = new SimplePie($source[url]);

$feed->handle_content_type();  

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)  
{  

    $title = $item->get_title();  
    $link = $item->get_link();
    $description = $item->get_content();

    // strip all html
    $description = strip_tags($description);

    // format the data to make sure it's all fine
    $title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    // create the path, or slug if you will
    $path = post_slug($title);

    $description = html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: You will need to show some code.

Comment: My instinct is that by un-blacklisting those tags, you're bringing in their attribute too, which may include `style="margin-top: 1000px"` or something similarly messy. Can you include an example of the content after `strip_tags`? We might be able to identify specific things left in that might have harmful interactions with the rest of your site.

Comment: Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

There are options for allowable tags.  And my guess is that the bad formatting is from missing closing or beginning tags in your exception list.

Comment: The documentation says: *Warning: Because `strip_tags()` does not actually validate the HTML, partial, or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.* Do you have valid HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you strip tags, process a string replace to convert the special characters you'd like to keep.

```
$source = str_replace('<p>', '&lt;p&gt;', $source);
$source = strip_tags($source);
```

Then use `htmlspecialchars_decode(trim($source))` to output to html.

I'm willing to bet that the cause of your page layout going awry is css related. Look through your generated source closely (if possible, with firebug) and make sure that every html element also has a corresponding close tag and that none of your intentional html elements have been changed by your script, though I don't know why they would be.

Try isolating the output of your script to a blank page so that you can get a close look at what's going on. Then once you're sure everything is where is aught to be, if problems persist, try placing the output in different parts of your page. Additionally, make sure you trim your whitespace.

Let us know what you find out.

Comment: Or just `strip_tags($source, '<p>')`... way easier.

Comment: Ha, ha! Sorry... Apparently I'm in "sql, prepare for form" mode today.

Comment: Anyway, I think the OP is already doing this. But he doe not get the desired results.